# Invalid object, expected stream

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am getting this error

> Type 'never' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

I know that error is related to my if statement in the code below (drivers.service.ts)

```html
export class DriversService {

  user: User;
  comp = '';
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private auth: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

 getUsers() {
  return this.auth.user.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(user => {
      //  user['company'];
      this.comp = user['company'];
      return user['company'];
    })
  )
 }

  findUser(value) {

    if(this.comp.length <= 0){
      return this.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
        this.comp = user;
        console.log('Bye', this.comp)
        return this.comp;
       });
    }

    let email = this.db.collection(`companies/${this.comp}/users`, ref => ref.where('email', '==', value)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      take(1)
    );
    let name = this.db.collection(`companies/${this.comp}/users`, ref => ref.where('name', '==', value)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      take(1)
    );
    return [email, name];
  }
```

And accutal error is showing in add-driver.page.ts in forkJoin()

```html
export class AddDriverPage implements OnInit {
 
  users = [];
  participant = '';
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private driverService: DriversService, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addDriver() {
    let obs = this.driverService.findUser(this.participant);

    forkJoin(obs).subscribe(res => {
      for (let data of res) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
          this.users.push(data[0]);
        }
      }
      console.log('it works:', this.participant)
      this.participant = '';
    });

  }
}
```

So how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Try to make an example in stackblitz. Easier to help.

Answer (score 3):

Change in your service function:

```
if (this.comp.length <= 0) {
      return [this.getUsers().pipe(map(user => {
        this.comp = user;
        console.log('Bye', this.comp);
        return this.comp;
       }))];
    }
```

Then in your component:

```
addDriver() {
    const obs = this.driverService.findUser(this.participant);

    forkJoin(obs).subscribe(res => {
      if (!res || !res.length) {
        return console.log('Got undefined');
      }
      for (let data of res) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
          this.users.push(data[0]);
        }
      }
      console.log('it works:', this.participant)
      this.participant = '';
    }, error => {
   console.log('Here you got an error: ', error);
});
  }
```

Comment: So I get rid off the error, but the problem is deeper than I think. Now it didn't return any data, it is empty from the first try. When I search second time it works. But I do not want that kind of user experience.

Comment: I have changed returned value to array type, as you expect from FireStore. Then merge observables results. Try this variant. And of course, overall code is not perfect...

Comment: > Type 'Observable<string> | Observable<{ id: string; }[]>[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator. This is error underlined in ...obs
> Found non-callable @@iterator This error was in the browser

Comment: Check it now please

Comment: Same problem, look into image for more details https://ibb.co/xfBzk4Q

Comment: How about with jorkJoin?

Comment: https://ibb.co/2sMB1tj -- we came back to the original problem

Comment: Check it now please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216895/discussion-between-roben-wayne-and-tony-marko).